# Map form field to eloquent model with different name

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I'm wondering how to map form field to eloquent model. Thing is that form input field has different name than eloquent model.

**This is what i have**

Model

```
class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'subject_id',
    ];
}
```

Form

```
<form action="{{ action('MessageController@store') }}" method="post">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text">
<input id="email" name="email" type="text">
<select id="subject" name="subject">
    @foreach ($subjects as $subject)
        <option value="{{ $subject->id }}">{{ $subject->title}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $message = $this->validate(request(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'subject' => 'required',
    ]);

    Message::create($message);
}
```

Notice that form select field name is `subject` and Message model field is `subject_id`.

Is it possible to map these two fields in Message model?
I guess it's possible in controller with something like

```
Message::create([
    'name' => $request->input('name');
    'email' => $request->input('email');
    'subject_id' => $request->input('subject');
]);
```

but that's not what i want.

I don't expect some code improvements or suggestions as i'm complete Laravel noob :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a mutator on the Message model.

```
public function setSubjectAttribute($value) {
      $this->attributes['subject_id'] = $value;
}
```

That essentially tells eloquent there is a `subject` attribute on the model but under the hood you're modifying `subject_id`